# How can we use different WAF rule over ALB target group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer, web-application-firewall

I use one ALB, and there are two target groups. I change the traffic by the host name.

- stg.example.com goes to stg target group.
- example.com goes to prd target group.

I'm thinking to use aws WAF to ALB.
I saw path matching condition, but it seems to be for URL resources such as /users, /admin
What I want to do is changing the WAF rule for stg and prd. How can I do this? Can we specify the target group or host name match?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [rule based](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/classic-web-acl-string-conditions.html) on [Referer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) header. The use of `Referer` is not a bulletproof solution as `Referer` can be spoofed, but it could suit your needs nevertheless.  Similarly you could look at a rule based on [All query parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-rule-statement-fields.html).